# Input number of days and return a future date

Tags: python

I was wondering that from the code below, is there a way to be able to incorporate a date saying from today (5/3/22) and if 20 days were to be added on it would show the future date as (25/3/22).

My code is listed below, hoping somebody could provide some assistance!

```
def fileBooking(custID, roomBook, target):
    fileBook = open("hotelBookings.txt", "a")

    fname = input("Please enter customer's first name: ")
    lname = input("Please enter customer's name: ")
    age = input("Please customer's age: ")
    country = input("Please enter customer's country and state: ")
    stnumber = input("Please enter customer's address: ")
    length = input("Please enter customer's length of stay: ")
    

    fileBook.write("---------------------------------------------------------" + "\n")
    fileBook.write("Booking ID: " + custID + "\n")
    fileBook.write("Hotel Location: " + target + "\n")
    fileBook.write("Full Name: " + fname + " " + lname + "\n")
    fileBook.write("Age: " + str(age) + "\n")
    fileBook.write("Country and State: " + country + "\n")
    fileBook.write("Customer Address: " + str(stnumber + "\n"))
    fileBook.write("Room Number: " + str(roomBook) + "\n")
    fileBook.write("Duration of Stay/Room Available After: " + length + "\n")
    fileBook.write("---------------------------------------------------------" + "\n")

    fileBook.close()
```

Comment: Hello! We'll need more information to help you out. What have you already tried and what specific issue did you have?

Comment: I will be much better if you use `with` statement.

Comment: You may find Python's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) useful.

Comment: @Seth i want to add the number of days in length to the current date of today, so when displayed it would show 6/3/22 + number of days e..g, 20 == 26/3/22

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module.  If you add a positive `datetime.timedelta` to a `datetime.datetime`, you get a `datetime.datetime` in the future:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=20)
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 25, 17, 0, 47, 168743)
```

Use `strftime()` to format the result however you want:

```
>>> (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=20)).strftime("%d/%m/%y")
'25/03/22'
```

Comment: is there a way you can incorporate this into my code?

Comment: Replace `20` with `int(length)`.

Comment: I tried this but got an error due to datetime.timedelta has no attribute strfttime: fname = input("Please enter customer's first name: ")
    lname = input("Please enter customer's name: ")
    age = input("Please customer's age: ")
    country = input("Please enter customer's country and state: ")
    stnumber = input("Please enter customer's address: ")
    length = int(input("Please enter customer's length of stay (no. of days): "))
    datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = int(length)).strfttime("%d/%m/%y")

Comment: That sounds like you haven't quite got the brackets right; double-check those? You want the addition to happen before the `strftime`

Comment: Ah, I see it: typo in `strftime`, no double t

Comment: @JiříBaum i still get this error: AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime' | any idea as to why?

Comment: Yeah, you need to add it to a `datetime.datetime` object first; check that you put the brackets around pieces right, or do it in multiple steps with intermediate results in different variables that you can print out for debugging